# What would you call someone who constantly is thinking of all scenarios/possibilities/outcomes?

Tags: single-word-requests, titles

If someone is the type of person who goes into a situation or conversation and before stepping in thinks of all the different things that could happen and how they would respond.

Example: If they ask me about this... I would say that... 
If this happens... I would do this...

Comment: Exhausted, presumably.

Comment: Unsettled? Flustered?

Comment: *Prepared*? *Organized*? You need to be more precise in terms of what kind of word you're looking for. Is it a good thing or a bad thing? What words have you ruled out, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Prescient might work

> **Prescient**
>   1. having prescience, or knowledge of things or events before
>   they exist or happen; having foresight

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prescient?s=t